# Node.js & Javascript / Date object - take time before x hours

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a script in node.js which find all files in specific directory, and takes it modified time:

```
 fs.stat(path, function(err, states){
                console.log(states.mtime)
 })
```

and it prints me the following:

```
Sun Aug 31 2014 11:40:14 GMT-0400 (EDT)
```

I want to print only files which was modified before 6 hours from now.

Is this Data object support it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fs.stat(path, function(err, states){
    if (state.mtime < new Date() - (6*60*60*1000)) {
        console.log(states.mtime)
    }
 })
```

Only print if the date is less than the current date - 6 hours.